# Stop a For Loop at an Index Value

Tags: python, loops, selenium

I am attempting to use a for loop to iterate through a list of items. I do not need all items in the list and would like to end on a certain index position. How would I go about this in python?

I've attempted to use enumerate and alter my code to other options. After hours of searching I am having a hard time understanding how to end a loop upon a certain parameter in python. The code I am providing WORKS excellent for my interests. I would only like to stop the for loop upon a certain index.

```
train_times = driver.find_element_by_class_name('stop-times').text
str(train_times)
train_times=train_times.split('\n')

print("Schedule for 900 East Station:")

for i in train_times:
    print('There is a train at {}'.format(i))
    print('--------------------------------------')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know the exact index to stop in the string you can provide the index to loop from and to

```
for i in train_times[:20]:
    print('There is a train at {}'.format(i))
    print('--------------------------------------')
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `break` for loops:

```py
train_times = driver.find_element_by_class_name('stop-times').text
str(train_times)
train_times=train_times.split('\n')

print("Schedule for 900 East Station:")

for i, train in enumerate(train_times):
    if i == 400:
        break
    print('There is a train at {}'.format(train))
    print('--------------------------------------')
```

See more about break on loops: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Answer (score 2):

You can use break and enumarate.

```py
for index, value in enumerate(train_times):
   if index == x : break
   // your code here
```